# Icon Column deletion

Tags: 2013, column

Hi I added my custom list an "Icon" column, but I'm not able to delete it from now on:

Like here in SharePoint Designer its grayed out:
[image]

and via the List Settings the "Delete" Button is not displayed:
[image]

I'm collection administrator so there should be no permission issue (due the option is available and working for all other columns)

Any idea how to get rid of the column?

Answer (score -1):

Try this powershell script.

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$web = Get-SPWeb "Web URL" 
$list = $web.Lists["List Name"] 
$field = $list.Fields["Description"] 
$field.AllowDeletion = $true
$field.Sealed = $false
$field.Delete() 
$list.Update() 

Remove-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
```